# How many triangles are there whose sides are prime numbers and have a perimeter equal to $29$?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, prime-numbers, triangles

> Perimeter of a triangle is equal to $29$ and the values of all three sides are prime number. How many many incongruent triangles we have with this properties?

> $1)2\qquad\qquad\qquad2)3\qquad\qquad\qquad3)4\qquad\qquad\qquad4)5$

First I realized that we can't have a side equal to $2$ because then perimeter will be even number. And we know that if $a,b,c$ are the values of sides we have:

$$a+b>c$$
Hence $29-c>c$ and $c<14.5$, similarly we have $a<14.5$  and $b<14.5$,  so we have $a,b,c\in\{3,5,7,11,13\}$ and $a+b+c=29$

From here is it possible to proceed without Try and Error ?

Comment: Why would one side $=2$ imply an even perimeter?

Comment: @lulu  Oh I forget the case that two sides can be $2$. but anyway in this case the third side is $25$ which is not a prime number.

Comment: Yes, that is a good argument for excluding $2$.

Comment: Beyond that, I think trial and error really is the way to go.  It's quite fast.

Comment: @lulu Yes, it seems the only way. thank you for the help!

Comment: @fGDu94 The longest side must be less than $\frac {29}2=14.5$ (the triangle condition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modulo $6$ the residues of the primes are $3,-1,1,-1,1$ respectively – and our target has residue $-1$ modulo $6$. If we use two $3$s the last side must be $23$, which is impossible. If we use one $3$ the other two sides must have residue $1$ each and sum to $26$ – the only possibility is $13$ and $13$. If no $3$s, there must be two residue $-1$ numbers and one residue $1$ number:

- If the residue $1$ number is $7$, we can only have $11$ and $11$
- If that number is $13$, we can only have $5$ and $11$

Hence there are $3$ incongruent admissible triangles: $\{3,13,13\},\{7,11,11\},\{5,11,13\}$.

Answer (score 1):

You have set up the problem really well.

Let's think about how trial and error would work.  The only solution with a $3$ in it is $3+13+13$.  Now, can we upgrade the $3$ to a $5$ and reduce $2$ from one of the other sides?  Yes, that would lead to $5+11+13$.  That is the only solution with a $5$.  Can we do it again?  Yes, but moving the $5$ to a $7$ has to be balanced by reducing the other $13$, because $9$ is not prime.  Therefore, $7+11+11$ is the only solution with a $7$ in it.

Since you couldn't have any solutions without a $3, 5,$ or $7$ with a total of $29$, those are the only three solutions.